# How to represent a math expression in spark SQL DSL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While I much prefer using straight `SQL` instead of the `DSL` there is a case where the latter is required: when we want to perform a custom aggregation on the rows of a grouping.

What I am uncertain about is how to then transform this straightforward computation to the `DSL`:

```
 100.0 * (count(*)-sum(dep_delayed))/count(*)
```

What is the equivalent in the `DSL` ?  Is it necessary to create a `UDF` (/ `AggUDF`) and if so how would that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across the answer today: use

```
 expr("some sql clause")
```

So the code can be implemented as

```
.agg(expr("100.0 * (count(*)-sum(dep_delayed))/count(*)"))
```